# Why am I getting this error "Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake."?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms, express

Hey guys and gals I am just trying to make a simple form that sends data to mySQL database. My problem is after I submit it I can't submit another one. It only allows me to submit the form once, and then after submitting it the second time I get this error "Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake." I have looked online and it seems that I need to restart the connection to mysql after each form submits. I have tried putting into a function, but can't seem to get it to work.

```html
//require packages

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//connect to our database

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "yourRootPassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

//joining index.html to get route
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

//setting post route to /submit >> how we post to database>>
app.post("/submit", function(req, res) {
  //req.body.nameOfInput
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  res.write('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".\n');
  res.write('You sent the email "' + req.body.email + '".\n');
  res.write('You sent the username "' + req.body.username + '".\n');
  //inserting data into sql var
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var sql =
      "INSERT INTO form (name, email,username) VALUES ('" +
      name +
      "', '" +
      email +
      "','" +
      username +
      "')";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
      res.end();
    });
  });
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting multiple times, without closing the connection. I use connection pools. The way you are doing it could cause massive build up of open connections, which will bring down server. I would also do a res.status(200).send("Insert completed"), but it looks like you have some debugging code.

```
var myPool;
function connect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool = mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit: 10,
            host     : this.host,
            user     : this.user,
            password : this.password,
            database : this.database
        });
        resolve(pool);
    });
}

connect().then(pool => {
    myPool = pool;
})

app.post("/submit", function(req, res) {
  //req.body.nameOfInput
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  res.write('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".\n');
  res.write('You sent the email "' + req.body.email + '".\n');
  res.write('You sent the username "' + req.body.username + '".\n');
  //inserting data into sql var
  myPool.getConnection((err, con) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var sql =
      "INSERT INTO form (name, email,username) VALUES ('" +
      name +
      "', '" +
      email +
      "','" +
      username +
      "')";
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
      con.release();
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That makes more sense however I have one question, where would i enter in my previous information for the connection like host user password database?

Comment: Never mind....that was a dumb question. Thank you very much :) that helped greatly I have never explored connection pools before.